# Function arguments: two different styles?

Tags: verilog

Reading some Verilog code, there seem to be two ways of defining arguments in function declaration:

Method 1:

```
function factorial;
    input [3:0] operand;
    // More code
endfunction
```

Method 2:

```
function factorial(input [3:0] operand);
    // More code
endfunction
```

Is there any difference between the two? Are both methods equally portable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe they are equivalent.

From a manual the definition of a function:

```
function [automatic] [signed] [RangeOrType] functionName [(FunctionPorts)];
 Declarations ...
 begin
  ...code...
 end
endfunction

FunctioPort
 input [reg]  [signed] [Range] names
 input [Type] names

Declaration
 input [reg]  [signed] [Range] names
 input [Type] names
 Variable
 Parameter
 Event
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Verilog 2001 standard, these two are equivalent.
Some old tools do not support Verilog 2001 or do not support in default.
So using method 1 is a little bit more compatible.

However, in general terms, you do not need to worry about it as nearly all the tools you use nowadays support Verilog 2001 in default.